# Are there any tools available for visualizing Predecessor / Successor relationships between TFS / VSTS work items?

Tags: azure-devops

My team is currently building up a backlog in VSTS online, and we're using the Predecessor / Successor relations between PBIs to try and ensure that we're doing work in the correct order. Are there any tools out there for visualizing the Predecessor / Successor relationships for a Product backlog / Sprint backlog in VSTS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with [Work Item Visualization](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.WorkItemVisualization) extension.

> In Visual Studio Team Services you can add, edit and display work
>   items in query results and various boards. With this extension you can
>   visualize these work items from within the work item form.